# What is the math and nomenclature for the results of a number of statistical trials equal to the odds?

Tags: statistics

I'm sure there's a name for this but I'm far enough out of my proper training that I've almost totally lost my statistics vocabulary so Im not even sure how to search for this on various databases.

Statistically, if you run a number of trials equal to the odds of your desired result, there is apparently always a 63% chance of having one or more positive result, for values 5% or lower. 100 trials of a 1 in 100(1%), 500 trials of a 1 in 500(0.2%), et cetera. Theres some variation after the decimal there, but it looks like it rapidly trends to 63.2% or so. (Specifically 36% for one success, 36% for more than one, 26% for zero successes, all numbers truncated for simplicity.)

Is there a name for this? Why does it happen? Is it related to the 68% rule of thumb for standard deviations?

For now I'm calling it The two-thirds rule because 63% is close enough to 67% that I can quickly apply this to probability calculations I run into when I don't have the luxury of a calculator. Making a personal rule of thumb.

Comment: Not following.  Suppose the odds are $3\,:\,7$.  How many trials do you run?

Comment: What do you mean by "number of trials equal to the odds of your desired result" ? The number of trials is an integer, whereas "the odds" is a real number between $0$ and $1$ ... Do you mean the inverse of the odds?

Comment: Maybe you can study the binomial distribution ...

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As you can see from the comments, it's hard to sort out your meaning.  Perhaps a numerical example would help.  Start with the situation I mentioned, with odds $3\,:\,7$.  How many trials do you run?  What calculation do you perform to get $63\%$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're considering repeated, independent trials of a random event $A$. The probability of this event occuring is $\frac{1}{x}$ (consider that $x$ is a large integer). The trial is repeated $x$ times. Now let's consider the probability that the event $A$ happens at least once during these $x$ trials. This can be calculated with the binomial distribution:
$$
P(A\text{ occurs at least once}) =  1- P(A\text{ occurs zero times}) = 1- \left(1- \frac{1}{x} \right)^x
$$
Now we are actually interested in what happens when $x \to \infty$. The proof is easy to find with Google (https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-limit-of-1-1-x-x-as-x-approaches-infinity) and it turns out that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{x} \right)^x = \frac{1}{e}
$$
where $e$ is the famous Euler's number. Therefore, 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} 1- \left(1 - \frac{1}{x} \right)^x = 1- \frac{1}{e} \approx 0.6321
$$

Comment: There we go, you put it much better than I can. Most of that proof is way over my head, but I got the gist of it. Thank you!